# Simplest automatic gain control circuit with BJT + op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, rf, control, gain

I'm trying to implement a simple automatic gain control to my amplifier circuit. What I'm amplifying is a small signal from a superregen receiver. Without the transistor and the passive components with no values marked (aka a basic amplifier), when I tune the radio, I sometimes hear it oscillate which gives me the indication that I'm in need of an agc. I want to eventually detect the output on an LED.

But for now, what I want to do is set an output limit so that if the input is too high, I won't hear oscillations.

Could this circuit I have posted be usable as a decent agc? If so, how can I calculate the proper values for C2, C1, R3 and R1?

[image: agc]

Comment: I don't think so. For a start, the collector current of Q1 is ill-defined, and I don't see any volume-detection (C2 will pass the current signal, which is something else).

Comment: LTSpice is your friend.

Comment: I'm new to volume detection but I would assume I need a resistor network of some sorts for that, and perhaps I need a diode in series with C1 to prevent input from messing up with Q1 collector? and I could try LTspice but I'm not running windows.